# Dynamically copying 5 columns in multiple sheets and saving it as .txt

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple files with the below sample format, where we need to extract 5 columns for "abc", and copy it into another sheet which will then be saved in ".txt" format named "abc.txt" (based on the value after _). We need to copy both Set1 and any other sets below it. The challenge is to copy 5 columns for all data, that is, abc, def, ghi, etc. The loop will run till there is not data in the columns.

We are stuck at this. Please help.

```
Set 1
```

Date  0_abc  5_abc   10_abc  15_abc  20_abc  0_def   5_def   10_def  15_def  20_def

1/1/2018 369 954 85  61  24  526 982 487 404 491

1/2/2018 662 881 379 778 853 328 430 996 776 508

1/3/2018 689 672 479 908 815 235 611 996 685 771

```
Set 2
```

Date 0_abc   5_abc   10_abc  15_abc  20_abc  0_def   5_def   10_def  15_def  20_def

1/1/2018 838 815 631 336 477 164 511 682 550 197

1/2/2018 195 344 454 645 37  516 425 904 971 676

____________

The output files will look like this:

abc.txt

Set 1

Date  0_abc  5_abc   10_abc  15_abc  20_abc

1/1/2018 369 954 85  61  24

1/2/2018 662 881 379 778 853

1/3/2018 689 672 479 908 815

```
Set 2
```

Date 0_abc   5_abc   10_abc  15_abc  20_abc

1/1/2018 838 815 631 336 477

1/2/2018 195 344 454 645 37

----------

def.txt

Set 1

Date  0_def  5_def   10_def  15_def  20_def

1/1/2018 526 982 487 404 491

1/2/2018 328 430 996 776 508

1/3/2018 235 611 996 685 771

```
Set 2
```

Date 0_def   5_def   10_def  15_def  20_def

1/1/2018 164 511 682 550 197

1/2/2018 516 425 904 971 676

____________

____________

Code Sample

```
Sub Final6()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("B:F").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("G:K").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("L:P").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("Q:U").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("V:Z").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your exact problem ? You need to give us a sample of your code.

Comment: We did make a static version of it, but unable to make it dynamic. I am pretty new to vba so would need your help.

Comment: Ok the original data is already in your sheet or do you want to import it from a file ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that you have worked on your problem instead of asking us to do the job. So  I'm just going to give you links and method to solve your issue. Working on that will help you to learn more about vba.

- [In order to find the last cell that contains something](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/)
- You then have to select your data (your 5 columns) and copy it to the other sheet ([here is some explanation on ranges](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html)) :

  Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range

  Set range1 = your_First_Sheet.Range(Cells(firstrow, firstcolumn), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))

  Set range2 = your_Second_Sheet.Range(Cells(firstrow, firstcolumn), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))

  range1.Copy range2
- [For the loop](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

I haven't done all the work but this will help you. However I'm giving you this that lets you save your data in a text file (because this one can be tricky) :

```
Dim filename As String, lineText As String, chemin As String
    Dim I As Integer, J As Integer
    Dim folder As FileDialog
Dim data as Range
Set data = your_sheet_you_want_in_your_file.Range(Cells(firstrow, firstcol),Cells(lastrow,lastcol))


Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'this is to ask the user where he wants to save the txt file
        folder.Show
        path = folder.SelectedItems(1)

    filename = path & "\" & Name_of_your_file & ".txt"

    Open filename For Output As #1

    For I = 1 To data.Rows.count
        For J = 1 To data.Columns.count
            lineText = Trim(IIf(J = 1, "", lineText & " ") & data.Cells(I, J))
        Next J
        Print #1, lineText
    Next I

    Close #1
MsgBox "Txt file created under :" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & filename
```

However I haven't tested it so come back to us when you have worked some more on your code

Comment: Hi, I cannot share the main data, however I have created a sample data which is similar to the main data and have also given the sample code. Now I'm trying to extract the first column and run a loop starting from the second column to the nth column(where 'n' can take any values, i.e. the column range is dynamic). I need to extract 5 columns at a time concatenate it with the first column(containing date), then create a separate worksheet and paste the same. I need to repeat  this(taking 5 columns each time and concatenating it with the first column) till i encounter a cell which is empty.

Comment: @SandipanChakraborty you're asking me to give you all the code. I don't have the time I'm sorry.  However I gave you all the tools you need and I feel like a big part of what you're asking is very easily found on google. Give it a try with some code you wrote thanks to what I gave you and post another question if you get stuck again. In addition to test if a cell is empty use: `If IsEmpty(Your_Sheet.Cells(Row, Col).Value) = True Then`